# Multi language update to 4.7 does not update Custom Field Sets to be 'is public'

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

Ran the update script and said it upgraded successfully... however, when running the Wordpress page where my subscription form was, got a No Such Field error...

It seems that the civicrm_custom_group_xx_XX views are not updated to include the is_public flag... The civicrm_custom_group table is updated, but not the views...

Comment: Note that I am using PHP 7.1 ...

Comment: is there another word that could be used instead of 'views' to avoid confusion with eg Drupal Views?

Comment: ok. now i am curious. this field got introduced in 4.7.x? I might fire up a new question.

Comment: The proper name for them is MySql views actually...

Answer (score 2):

While the patch in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10399/files will fix the issue for future site upgrades, it won't help with site that are already experiencing this issue. Running the following will fix sites affected by this issue:

```
drush eval 'civicrm_initialize(); $domain = new CRM_Core_DAO_Domain(); $domain->find(TRUE); if ($domain->locales) { $locales = explode(CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR, $domain->locales); CRM_Core_I18n_Schema::rebuildMultilingualSchema($locales, NULL); }'
```

Comment: I would imagine there is similar way of doing eval stuff using wp-cli for those on wordpress, I'm not sure about joomla but they could also look into cv as well

Answer (score 1):

In case others have the same issue, you need to fix the views manually by redefining them to include the 'is_public' field... You need to do this for each language in your database...

For example, I updated my fr_CA language (civicrm_custom_group_fr_CA) view as so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`coalitioncivi`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `civicrm_custom_group_fr_CA`
AS SELECT
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`id` AS `id`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`name` AS `name`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`extends` AS `extends`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`extends_entity_column_id` AS `extends_entity_column_id`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`extends_entity_column_value` AS `extends_entity_column_value`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`style` AS `style`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`collapse_display` AS `collapse_display`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`weight` AS `weight`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`is_active` AS `is_active`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`table_name` AS `table_name`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`is_multiple` AS `is_multiple`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`min_multiple` AS `min_multiple`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`max_multiple` AS `max_multiple`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`collapse_adv_display` AS `collapse_adv_display`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`created_id` AS `created_id`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`created_date` AS `created_date`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`is_reserved` AS `is_reserved`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`title_fr_CA` AS `title`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`help_pre_fr_CA` AS `help_pre`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`help_post_fr_CA` AS `help_post`,
   `civicrm_custom_group`.`is_public` AS `is_public`
FROM `civicrm_custom_group`;
```

Did the same for my en_US view... and all is working... hope that is the only issue...